# R new variable assignment

Tags: r

I made a loop that assigns the result of a function to a newly created variable. After that that variable is used to create another.
This second step fails to produce the expected result.

```
library(stringr)
for (i in 1:length(Ids)){
    nam <- paste("data", Ids[i], sep = "_")
    assign(nam, GetReportData(query, token,paginate_query = F))
    newvar=paste(nam,"contentid",sep="$")
    originStr=paste(nam,"pagePath",sep="$")
    assign(newvar,str_extract(originStr,"&id=[0-9]+"))
}
```

Comment: What are you *really* trying to do? Using `assign()` is generally not necessary. It's almost always better to store related values in a list rather than separate variables in the environment.  Plus you can never use assign with names that have "$" as described in the help page: "assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't create a bunch of variables, store related values in named lists to make it easier to retrieve them. You didn't supply any input to test with, but i'm guessing this does the same thing.

```
library(stringr)
mydata <- lapply(1:length(Ids), function(i) {
    dd <- GetReportData(query, token,paginate_query = F))
    dd$contentid <- str_extract(d$pagePath,"&id=[0-9]+"))
    dd
})
```

This will return a list of data.frames. You can access them with `mydata[[1]]`, `mydata[[2]]`, etc rather than `data_1`, `data_2`, etc

If you absolutely insist on creating a bunch of variables, just make sure to do all your transformations on an actual object, and then save that object when your are done. You can never use assign with names that have `$` or `[` as described in the help page: "assign does not dispatch assignment methods, so it cannot be used to set elements of vectors, names, attributes, etc." For example

```
for(i in 1:length(Ids)) {
    dd <- GetReportData(query, token,paginate_query = F))
    dd$contentid <- str_extract(d$pagePath,"&id=[0-9]+"))
    assign(paste("data",i,sep="_"), dd)
}
```